# Can't Install Ubuntu in Asus K42F

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, 18.04, software-installation

I had problem in Ubuntu Install process, after select option "Install" in grub menu laptop doesn't give response (blank), I have tried to replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" laptop still doesn't give response, I did this method for 3 version ubuntu (14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04) for 32bit & 64bit
I doubt whether Ubuntu can be run on my device? detail specs as follow ------------------

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 8/23/2019, 05:46:57
         Machine name: DESKTOP-MU7BR3I
  System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
         System Model: K42F
                 BIOS: BIOS Date: 06/15/09 18:50:05 Ver: 08.00.10 (type: BIOS)/ version 503
            Processor: i3 m350
               Memory: 3072MB RAM
            Page File: 1310MB used, 3087MB available
             Miracast: Not Available
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.17763.0001 64bit Unicode

---

### Display Devices

```
       Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
       Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i3)
        DAC type: Internal
     Device Type: Full Device (POST)
  Display Memory: 1526 MB
Dedicated Memory: 64 MB
   Shared Memory: 1462 MB
    Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
     HDR Support: Not Supported
Display Topology: Internal
```

Display Color Space: DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709
        Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
       Monitor Model: unknown
          Monitor Id: AUO183C
         Native Mode: 1366 x 768(p) (60.098Hz)
         Output Type: Internal
Monitor Capabilities: HDR Not Supported
Display Pixel Format: DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP
      Advanced Color: Not Supported

currently I use windows 10, please help I want to migrate to Ubuntu

Comment: I mean, I already tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, 16.04 LTS 32bit, 16.04 LTS 64bit, 18.04 LTS 64bit, but no one success, I had same problem in install process, I was deadlocked on how to install ubuntu, can you help me??

Comment: Did you verify the download (of ISO)? and write to media?  When Ubuntu boots you can 'check disc for errors' which will do both (ie. ensure your download & write to media was flawless).

Comment: even I couldn't did check disc for error, since when I select chek disc screan blank, I am affraid my device not support for ubuntu

Comment: I would say that points more to bad download OR write to media was bad, unless you performed the validation on another box and had no errors.  *because you tried multiple downloads (3 iso's), it's most likely bad write to media (the common link)*

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your advice, I will try to download the ISO again and write to use another PC's USB, 3GB RAM still usable for ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 right?

Comment: Finally, I m success install ubuntu 16.04.6 after redownload ISO file an upgrade BIOS, thank for share knowlage